# Move components in dom around without 'destroying component'

Tags: angular

I'd like to find a way to move my component around in the DOM without destroying the component. I want the component to stay initialized. Here's what I have so far:

```
<div *ngIf="conditionIsTrue">
  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="myComponentContainer"></ng-container>
</div>

<div *ngIf="conditionIsFalse">
  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="myComponentContainer"></ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #myComponentContainer>
  <my-component>
  </my-component>
</ng-template>
```

My set up works, the component gets injected into different divs based on the condition, but because of this setup (ngIfs), the component gets destroyed and reinitialized. I can't have this happen. What can I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `hidden` html attribute to hide the content without destroying it.

```
[hidden]="!myboolean"
```

`ngIf` will remove the content from DOM when the expression evaluates to false. But, `hidden` will only hide the content using CSS `display` property.